# SPFX Sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, webapi

I created an app in spfx on sharepoint online and connect to a app service use AadClient. It's possible to do the same in SharePoint 2019 On Premise  and On Premise Api?.

Thanks

Comment: As long as the features you need from SPFx are supported in SPFx 1.41, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

How can I send the authenticated SPFX user token to the web API?

Comment: Is there a way to determine what version of SPFx is available on premise in the future? Do CU's/patches update this? How long will on-prem be stuck on 1.41?